# GitHub hosted Jeykll site. Background images within css are not displaying?

Tags: github, jekyll

I've created a settings.yml within a _data folder. This also contains my baseurl: */run-and-roll*.

So I have inserted `{{ site.data.settings.baseurl }}` in front of my assets. The *css* file is loading along with images that are defined in the *html*. However, any background images requested in the css are not showing?

https://granttransition.github.io/run-and-roll/

Comment: Perhaps add a trailing slash to the `baseurl`?

Comment: The training slash is already follows the {{ site.data.settings.baseurl }}. So my header background images has, background-image: url({{ site.data.settings.baseurl }}/assets/img/runner.jpg);. For some reason GitHub appears to be outputting the /run-and-roll url everywhere, bar the css which outputs as {{ site.data.settings.baseurl }}/assets/img/...

Comment: Why didn't you add the `baseurl` in `_config.yml`? Can you give an example of the current behaviour?

Comment: Mainly because I read it was good practice to have settings and config separate. Happy to be corrected. Currently, the css outputs {{ site.data.settings.baseurl }}/assets/img/runner.jpg) instead of run-and-roll/assets/img/runner.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

Every configuration variable that appears in https://jekyllrb.com/docs/configuration/ makes sense to keep them there.

Usually templates preppend the base url when generating some urls like the ones of the assets, using `{{site.baseurl}}`, so if you manually sets it from another location it won't be used by default.

What you have read that is a good practice to have settings and config separate is for every other configuration not related exactly with jekyll built-in variables, that it is a good practice to put them on data files, so you keep your `_conf.yml` as clear as possible as the official docs [suggests](https://jekyllrb.com/docs/datafiles/), that makes easier to maintain and update your Jekyll instance:

> In addition to the built-in variables available from Jekyll, you can
>   specify your own custom data that can be accessed via the Liquid
>   templating system.
>
> Jekyll supports loading data from YAML, JSON, and CSV files located in
>   the _data directory. Note that CSV files must contain a header row.
>
> This powerful feature allows you to avoid repetition in your templates
>   and to set site specific options without changing _config.yml.
>
> Plugins/themes can also leverage Data Files to set configuration
>   variables.

Answer (score 1):

## TL;DR

just put `baseurl` in `_config.yml` as suggested in other answers :)

b/c if you are using Jekyll with Github Page, then if `site.url` or `site.baseurl` are not specified, in a `CNAME` or `config.yml`, for the [production build](https://jekyllrb.com/docs/configuration/#specifying-a-jekyll-environment-at-build-time). then they will be set automatically by [github page generator](https://github.com/jekyll/github-metadata/blob/a8a64bef6e1bd4b1f0b78fc10f18228d565b2972/lib/jekyll-github-metadata/ghp_metadata_generator.rb#L38)

## Explanation

from [github page generator](https://github.com/jekyll/github-metadata/blob/a8a64bef6e1bd4b1f0b78fc10f18228d565b2972/lib/jekyll-github-metadata/ghp_metadata_generator.rb#L38) code-source:

```ruby
  # Set `site.url` and `site.baseurl` if unset and in production mode.
  def set_url_and_baseurl_fallbacks!
    return unless Jekyll.env == "production"

    repo = drop.send(:repository)
    site.config["url"] ||= repo.url_without_path
    if site.config["baseurl"].to_s.empty? && !["", "/"].include?(repo.baseurl)
      site.config["baseurl"] = repo.baseurl
    end
  end
```

the default build environment for jekyll, is `development`. So while, working on your site locally. every thing will run just as you expect. even when putting `baseurl` in other location than `_config.yml`

but in github page side, the web site is built with this command:

```
JEKYLL_ENV=production jekyll build
```

and `site.url` and `site.baseurl` are overridden.

in your case, if you're using `{{ site.data.settings.baseurl }}` to access some page, and it's set to a value like (`''` or `'/'`) you may not notice a navigation issue. bat `assets path` for css and js will not work as expected.

So, just put `baseurl` in the `_config.yml`, refactor your layout and pages accordingly. and you'll be fine.

**a side note**: as mentioned in @David answer, it's the jekyll convention to put website setting. in `_config.yml`, but if you want to put them in other place, you can. just make sure, to declare them for the `production` build as will.

see also: [Clearing Up Confusion Around baseurl -- Again](https://byparker.com/blog/2014/clearing-up-confusion-around-baseurl/)

## UPDATE

even after moving the website to a github project [repo](https://github.com/granttransition/run-and-roll): `/<user-name>.github.io/<repo-name>` instead of user (or organization) repo: `/<user-name>.github.io`. you need to set as follows:

```
site.baseurl: ''
```

or just remove it. since you serve your website from the main repository (cf. [above refence](https://byparker.com/blog/2014/clearing-up-confusion-around-baseurl/))

Answer (score 0):

Use of `{{ site.baseurl }}` is a jekyll convention, moving it to a data file is not a good idea.

Nevertheless from your css standpoint, path to `runner.jpg` will always be `../assets/img/runner.jpg`. No need to use `baseurl`.

Comment: Even on live site?

Comment: Yep ! `../assets/img/runner.jpg` is a path relative to your style-sheet that will never move.

Comment: Followed the advise, still not displaying background images? https://granttransition.github.io/run-and-roll/. https://www.dropbox.com/s/pbtoaz630fbmllf/Screenshot%202017-01-24%2015.22.21.png?dl=0

Comment: `background-image: url("../aassets/img/pattern.png");` will not work.

Comment: Corrected the spelling mistake, but still doesn't any background images…

Comment: I've checked your repo again, I think that you don't actually need this: `baseurl: /run-and-roll`